# How can I set dynamic values in filename-pattern="*.*" Is it possible?

Tags: ftp, spring-integration

*I want to give dynamic values in file-pattern is it possible*

```
<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound1"
            channel="ftpChannel1"
            session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
            filename-pattern="*.docx"
            auto-create-local-directory="true"
            delete-remote-files="false"
            remote-directory="${remoteDir}"
            local-directory="${localDir}">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="12000" max-messages-per-poll="100"/>
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

*Can any one help me to do?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add as many as you want; just give them different `id`s - they can all feed the same channel (or different).